# paramiko python script for linux command execution

Tags: python, linux, top-command

```
_stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command("top -c")   
print(_stdout.read().decode())  
print(_stderr.read().decode())
client.close()
```

output:
TERM environment variable not set.

i am not getting top command output, please help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `get_pty=True`

```
_stdin, _stdout, _stderr = client.exec_command('top -c', get_pty=True)
while buffer := _stdout.read(4096):
    print(buffer.decode())
```

Answer (score 0):

try code shown below,

```
_stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command("export TERM=xterm \n top -c")   
print(_stdout.read().decode())  
print(_stderr.read().decode())
client.close()
```

Comment: Throwing error .  top: failed tty get

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).